# Heroku: Unable to upgrade Review Apps

Tags: heroku, heroku-pipelines

Heroku tells me `A new version of Review Apps is available`, but when I click `upgrade`, but I get the following error

```
Invalid request. #: failed schema #/definitions/review-app-
config/links/0/schema: "repo" wasn't supplied.
```

Has anyone encountered this error yet? I'm not sure how to interpret it or how to resolve it.

Comment: I'd advise on NOT upgrading to the new version of Review Apps... it's not as good, several things are broken compared to the older version and Heroku - Config Vars don't inherit, Collaborators are not auto added anymore and more

Answer (score 4):

That error is displayed when you don't have a repo associated with your pipeline.

Inside your pipeline go to settings, and select a repo under the "Connect to Github" section